# Fatal error created while trying to use removeAllChildren() and removeAllActions() before reloading a SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

this is my first question on Stack Overflow, so yeah.. Anyway, I tried to create a "reload" button for my SKScene. To do so, I created a new SKSpriteNode subclass called "EDSpriteNodeButton". Into this subclass file, I created a protocol, so I can access a method from my scene. Here's my protocol code :

```
protocol EDSpriteNodeButtonDelegate: AnyObject {
func spriteNodeButtonPressed(_ button: EDSpriteNodeButton)
}
```

I then went back to my level scene and added my custom delegate...

```
class Level1Scene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, EDSpriteNodeButtonDelegate {
```

I then set my SKSpriteNode(which I'm using as my button)'s class to "EDSpriteNodeButton", made a `var` from my button, then made it a childNode and called my method at the bottom of my class.

```
var reloadSceneButton = EDSpriteNodeButton()

reloadSceneButton = self.childNode(withName: "reloadSceneButton") as! EDSpriteNodeButton
reloadSceneButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
reloadSceneButton.delegate = self

func reloadSceneRequested(_ button: EDSpriteNodeButton) {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeAllActions()
    self.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(self, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0))
```

But when `reloadSceneRequested()` is called, I get a fatal error:

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Does anyone know how to get my SKScene to reload completely (Like if it was the first time it was running)?

Comment: can you tell on which line number you are getting this force unwrap crash? And if case you don't know the line number, add "exception breakpoint" and intentionally crash it, control will stop at the line causing this crash.

Comment: Hey @Dipika ,  my fatal error is on the highest "self.childNode(withName:"")". If I make one a comment, by adding "//" at the beginning, the second is now the one that creates the error... Looks like it's not able to create or remove the childNode... or not able to recreate the child just after it was removed..

Comment: 1. check return type of childNode(withName: ) method, surely it is not returning EDSpriteNodeButton type and you are forcefully casting(as!) it in EDSpriteNodeButton type. 2. Don't forcefully casting the result of childNode(withName: ) instead put a guard there.  Can help better if you update with your childNode(withName: ) method.

Comment: Hey @Dipika , thanks for the help! I just changed all my vars which were like : `nameOfTheVar = EDSpriteNodeButton()` to `nameOfTheVar : EDSpriteNodeButton?` and added my question marks everywhere it had an error.. So a big thank you and if you want me to set your last comment as the solution, just copy/paste it as an answer! Have a good day!

Comment: Don't add question marks everywhere, that is going to break your code. Your problem is `reloadSceneButton` is not on your scene,  that is why it is crashing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it but I already have created a `var reloadSceneButton : EDSpriteNodeButton?`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check return type of childNode(withName: ) method, surely it is not returning EDSpriteNodeButton type and you are forcefully casting(as!) it in EDSpriteNodeButton type.
2. Don't forcefully casting the result of childNode(withName: ) instead put a guard there.